# SQL runs on localhost but throws SQLSTATE[42883] error on deployment to heroku

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

i have a laravel/vuejs project i just deployed to heroku. Everything works well both on local and production except for a query that is throwing up SQLSTATE[42883] error on production. The sql query retrieves a count of models created every week:

```
public function getProductWeeklyData(){
    $products= Product::selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS product_count')
            ->selectRaw('FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(created_at) -MOD(TO_DAYS(created_at) -1, 7)) AS week_starting')
            ->groupBy('week_starting')
            ->orderBy('week_starting')
            ->take(10)->get();
    $products->each->setAppends([]);

    return response()->json($products, 200);
}
```

This works on localhost and return an array like so:

```
0: {product_count: 7, week_starting: "2021-10-31"}
1: {product_count: 12, week_starting: "2021-11-07"}
2: {product_count: 15, week_starting: "2021-11-14"}
```

which was exactly what i wanted.
However, after deploying to heroku and changing the database connection to PostgreSQL, the query fails and start returning this error.

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function to_days(timestamp without time zone) does not exist\nLINE 1: select COUNT(*) AS product_count,FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(created_at...\n                                                  ^\nHINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select COUNT(*) AS product_count, FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(created_at) -MOD(TO_DAYS(created_at) -1, 7)) AS week_starting from "products" group by "week_starting" order by "week_starting" asc limit 10)"

i tried casting the date like was suggested in the error by doing this

> ...(created_at::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
> but still got an error of invalid query.
> How do i get this query working with PostgreSQL on production?

Comment: What does `FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(created_at) -MOD(TO_DAYS(created_at) -1, 7))` do? What result does it return?

Comment: This is another good example why you shouldn't be testing with a different database than the one you use in production.

Comment: This ordinarily shouldn't be a problem. Laravel on localhost by default works with both but most test are done easily using mysql. However, while testing out your app on heroku, they give u free postgres add-on.